# Unable to upsize browser window both manually and programmatically

Tags: chart.js, responsive

```js
const options = {
      responsive: true,
};
```

When I downsize my browser it resizes fine, but if I upsize it, it doesn't (the chart stays the same size).

I have multiple charts. I want to handle it.

I tried to solve it with `onResize : function() {}`, but it also works only when downsizing the window.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Set the `maintainAspectRatio` to false.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Chart,js v4 and higher. Unfortunately it has been there for a while and it has not been fixed yet. Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11005)

And here are some hot fixes that can help you (taken from the github issue):

1. Setting an aspect ratio of a parent container

```
<div class="chart-container" style="aspect-ratio: 2">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

2. Setting the size of the canvas to 100%

```
canvas {
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 100% !important;
}
```

3. Adding an empty sibling element (that's what I used)

```
return (
  <Box>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <Chart .../>
  </Box>
)
```